# Set up Relative Path for a all $https Call in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new angularJS.
I have make call more then 10 $http request using services in my project.
One service code is given below.

```
loginApp.factory('serviceAuth', function($http) {
return {
    fnLoginAuth : function(aut,resp){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'http://localhost:8080/myProjectname/serviceName', 
        }).success(function(result) {
               return result;
        });
    }
}
```

});

I want **`http://localhost:8080/myProjectname/`** this part of url is configurable or use a variable  instead of this URL.

Answer (score 1):

In my applications written in *AngularJS*, I just put the variable in the `$rootScope`.

```
app.run(['$rootScope',
    function($rootScope) {
        $rootScope.serverRoot = '/projectname/public';
    }
]);
```

And append it to the services.

```
this.addTask = function(data) {
    return $http.post($rootScope.serverRoot + '/task/create', data);            
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you add another service that returns the base URL?

```
app.factory('urlService', function() {
var url = "";
return {
    setUrl : function(newUrl){
        url = newUrl;
    },
    getUrl : function(){
        return url;
    }
}
});
```

and use it like this:

```
app.run(function(urlService) {
    urlService.setUrl('http://localhost:8080/myProjectname/');
})

loginApp.factory('serviceAuth', function($http, urlService) {
return {
    fnLoginAuth : function(aut,resp){
        return $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: urlService.getUrl() + 'serviceName', 
        }).success(function(result) {
               return result;
        });
    }
}
});
```

Comment: Can we set up this path from a config file which is located root on our project

Comment: I prefer setting up the path in the run() section of the app. I have modified my answer and added a setUrl() and getUrl() to the urlService to reflect this.